# Displaying EMG (Electromyography) with PyQT Python

Tags: python, qt, graph, pyqt

I have to display an elecromyography (it's like an electrocardiogram) based on values i get from another file. Is there any widget in python Qt which will allow me to do that ?

What i want is something which will look like this picture :

[Example of EMG](https://www.google.be/search?q=EMG&espv=210&es_sm=93&tbm=isch&imgil=xYoq7tArEXcvOM%253A%253Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fencrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com%252Fimages%253Fq%253Dtbn%253AANd9GcThnDKPyRDGH-Lj_sGR1IO9JqBFXQCssDLkojp2wYgzcmt14dJ-BQ%253B692%253B685%253BYuQAfdjK_ztEaM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.azadehkhorram.com%25252Fsynergos-multiple-muscle-activation-azadeh-khorram%25252F&source=iu&usg=__E8ebgH-DNRKR76zm3I7X3kdeE94=&sa=X&ei=ZhQrU_e6A4aUhQfTl4HACw&ved=0CFMQ9QEwBA#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=vA_CqYnkqi1cbM%253A;bmRXu3iYGGJYJM;http%253A%252F%252Fwww.biomed.drexel.edu%252Flabs%252Fbiomechanics%252Fimages%252Femg_fig3.gif;http%253A%252F%252Fwww.biomed.drexel.edu%252Flabs%252Fbiomechanics%252Femg_analy.htm;583;359)

So, a graph based on the time (x) and voltages (y)

Thx for your help !

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in widget that will directly give you anything as complex as an EMG graph, so you would have to write something yourself using Qt's [Graphics View Framework](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html), which would obviously be quite a lot of work.

For out-of-the-box solutions, you could try something like [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) (Qt Widgets for Technical Applications), for which [PyQwt](http://pyqwt.sourceforge.net/) provides python bindings. Or there's also [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/), which has a [backend](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html?highlight=backend#what-is-a-backend) which provides support for PyQt/Qt.

**UPDATE**:

As has been pointed out, there's also [PyQtGraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/). But rather than list all the possibilities here, it would probably be easier to just point you towards the [Graphical Representations of Data](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific/Plotting) page on the Python Wiki.